# SQL Server Procedure for reports

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HelpDeskCalls
(
     RefID int, 
     TaskID tinyint, 
     Description nvarchar(4000), 
     EnteredBy int
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.HelpDeskUsers
(
     Users bigint, 
     Name nvarchar(4000), 
     Surname nvarchar(4000), 
     AllowedToLog int
)
GO

INSERT INTO HelpDeskCalls 
VALUES (1, 1, 'PC not working', 1),
       (1, 2, 'Technician sent', 2),
       (1, 3, 'Antivirus updated', 2),
       (1, 4, 'Case Closed', 1),
       (2, 1, 'Change password', 3),
       (2, 2, 'Password changed', 2),
       (2, 3, 'Case closed', 3),
       (3, 1, 'Replace monitor', 4),
       (3, 2, 'Monitor replaced', 2),
       (3, 3, 'Case closed', 4),
       (3, 4, 'Monitor still faulty', 4),
       (3, 5, 'Monitor replaced again', 2),
       (3, 6, 'Case closed', 4)
   
INSERT INTO HelpDeskUsers 
VALUES (1, 'Bob', 'Smith', 1),
       (2, 'John', 'Doe', 1),
       (3, 'Peter', 'Well', 1),
       (4, 'Mary', 'Williams', 1),
       (5, 'Berry', 'Andrews', 0)
```

I need to write a stored procedure that will add an entry to `HelpDeskCalls`.

For new entries, `RefID` must be sequential. For updates to existing tasks, the `TaskID` must be sequential.

Only the users that are allowed to log entries can do so.

Calls are closed, but can be reopened if the user not satisfied with the outcome.

I am lost. Please assist

Comment: Lost on so many levels. Firstly, learning sql should concentrate on learning sql - not on proper database design. Your schema mistakes will infect your code and your learning leading to mistaken ideas of how to write sql and bad habits. I suggest you start with a stub of a procedure - this is basic code development technique that works with any language. You know how to do that - just figure out what parameters are needed.

Comment: all i need is a starting point for the following: For new entries, RefID must be sequential. For updates to existing tasks, the TaskID must be sequential.